# Select items with a condition in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[This guide](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/select-items-with-if-statement-in-d3js.html) is helpful for styling `values <= 400` in red.

```
.style("fill", function(d) {           
    if (d.name <= 400) { return "red" }
    else { return "black" }         
;})
```

I would like to know how to return a specific string for custom styling. I've tried this

```
.style("fill", function(d) {           
    if (d['title'] = "blog") { return "red" }
    else { return "black" }         
;})
```

I'd also like to be able to select an array. For example, I would like all elements generated with the array collection to be red. How would I go about doing this?

```
collection = [{
  "title" : "Blog",
  "categories" : [ "Category-1", "Category-2" ]
}], 

library = [{
  "title" : "Blog",
  "categories" : [ "Category-1", "Category-2" ]
},];
```

Comment: Is your question a typo and your actual code is d['title'] == "blog"?

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @George got it correct. There is a problem in your if condition.
`d['title'] = "blog"` actually assigns the string "blog" to `d.title`. What you need is a `boolean` comparison.

```
.style("fill", function(d) {           
        if (d['title'] == "blog") {return "red"} 
        else    { return "black" }         
    ;})
```

Comment: Thanks and if (data == collection) {return "red"} colours the array. It works

Comment: If you wouldn't mind helping with one more thing, If I wanted to select only the "title" : "blog" string that is the array "collection" how would I do this?  I'm trying if (data == collection || d['title'] == "blog") { return ...

Comment: Can you ask a seperate question and provide the link?